# Find two columns in a table using specified headers, difference all rows then calculate average?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I have a table of information, and I would like to create a function that would find two columns in a table range that match the headers that I provide, then store the difference between each of the rows of the two columns as an array. After getting this array, I want the function to return the average, max and min of the array. The output will be horizontal and placed in 3 adjacent cells.

I am not doing this manually as the table is quite large and I have to get the difference and average of many permutations (435 permutations) of two rows, so manual calculation would be too tedious.

```
Function MatchDiff(header1 As String, header2 As String, tbl As Range) As Variant()
Dim c, r, a, Lcol As Single
Dim temp_spreads(), temp_final() As Variant
Dim Average As Double
Dim tbl1, tbl2 As Range

ReDim temp_diff(0)
ReDim temp_final(0)

For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count

    If header1 = tbl.Cells(1, c) Then
        tbl1 = tbl.Range(tbl.Cells(2, c), tbl.Cells(tbl.Rows.Count, c))

    ElseIf header2 = tbl.Cells(1, c) Then
        tbl2 = tbl.Range(tbl.Cells(2, c), tbl.Cells(tbl.Rows.Count, c))
    End If
Next c

For r = 1 To tbl1.Rows.Count
    temp_diff(UBound(temp_diff)) = (tbl1.Cells(r, 1).Value - tbl2.Cells(r, 1).Value)
    ReDim Preserve temp_diff(UBound(temp_diff) + 1)
Next r

Average = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(temp_diff)
temp_final(UBound(temp_final)) = Average
ReDim Preserve temp_final(UBound(temp_final) + 1)

Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(temp_diff)
temp_final(UBound(temp_final)) = Min
ReDim Preserve temp_final(UBound(temp_final) + 1)

Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(temp_diff)
temp_final(UBound(temp_final)) = Max
ReDim Preserve temp_final(UBound(temp_final) + 1)

Lcol = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Rows.Count
For a = UBound(temp_final) To Lcol
    temp_final(UBound(temp_final)) = ""
    ReDim Preserve temp_final(UBound(temp_final) + 1)
Next a

ReDim Preserve temp_final(UBound(temp_final) - 1)
MatchDiff = temp_final
End Function
```

This is what I have tried to do but it returns an invalid name error. I am extremely new to vba (have only used python and R) and really need some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line is it throwing a name error on ? Have you tried Option Explicit (goes before your function starts) ? This really helps narrow down errors.

Comment: You need to use the `Set` keyword to assign objects, eg `Set tbl1 = ...` and as @Mitch says you really do need `Option Explicit`. `Stats = temp_final` should throw a compile error if you do. You should also be aware that this won't work if it's a UDF.

Comment: @Ambie I've added Option Explicit but still unsure how to narrow down the errors. How would you guys write a function for this?

Comment: I can't really see what your code is trying to do (for example, tbl2 is defined but never used). Can you edit your question to include: 1) sample tables; 2) how you want to call the function; 3) where and how you want to write the data to your sheet..

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA.

If `headers` is the range representing the header labels and `data` the range representing the data (excluding the header row) then

```
=INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header1,headers,0))
```

provides an array corresponding to the column of your data table labelled `header1`.

So, your maximum, minimum and average values can be simply obtained as

```
=MAX(INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header1,headers,0))-INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header2,headers,0)))
=MIN(INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header1,headers,0))-INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header2,headers,0)))
=AVERAGE(INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header1,headers,0))-INDEX(data,0,MATCH(header2,headers,0)))
```

where `header1` and `header2` are your two selected header labels.

Each formula needs to be entered as an array formula using `CTL+SHIFT+ENTER` rather just `ENTER` when committing from the formula bar. The formula will then appear inside curly braces `{...}` in the formula bar confirming it is an array formula.

Since you have 435 permutations, I'm guessing that your data table has 30 columns.

If you wanted to, you could easily generate the results for all 435 possible permutations.

To do this create a list of 435 pairs `(n,m)` such that `n` is less than `m` and `n`, `m` are each in range 1,...,30. Create the list starting from `(1,2)` and ending at `(29,30)`. Now `MATCH(header1,headers,0)` and `MATCH(header2,headers,0)` can simply be replaced by `n` and `m`, respectively in the formulae to give

```
=MAX(INDEX(data,0,n)-INDEX(data,0,m))
=MIN(INDEX(data,0,n)-INDEX(data,0,m))
=AVERAGE(INDEX(data,0,n)-INDEX(data,0,m))
```

as the required results for pair `(n,m)`, where again these formulae should be entered as array formulae with `CTL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

The picture below shows the results of applying this approach for all 15 permutations of an example data table with 25 rows and 6 columns.
[image]